# Portable way to write Python 3 shebang?

Tags: python, portability, shebang

Back when Python3 was there, I used to use:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

But recently, especially with Ubuntu 22.04 or macOS, the `python3` executable isn't always available in `PATH`, instead, I should use `python` to call `python3`.

Is there any portable way to write Python3 shebang?

Comment: Wait, Ubuntu 22.04 removed `python3`? I'm still on 20.04 myself. I checked the dependencies online and it still seems to be there: [ubuntu-desktop](https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/ubuntu-desktop) -> software-properties-gtk -> python3 -> python3-minimal: `/usr/bin/python3`; and ubuntu-server -> software-properties-common -> python3.

Comment: sudo apt install python-is-python3

Comment: For true portability use a virtualenv through pyenv.  Then your system does pyenv activate my_python3.x.y_env and just runs the script with a normal shebang.  Using a virtualenv and pyenv removes all dependencies on the system python and problems with package dependencies.

Comment: The installation process will replace any shebang containing the word `python` with whatever is used to actually install your script. `#!python` would suffice. You as the *author* of the code shouldn't worry about where the *user* keeps the version of Python they'll use to execute it.

Comment: Easier to symlink `python3 -> python` in `/usr/bin` or the like than to muck around tons of shebangs, IMHO.

Comment: @JayM python-is-python3 is the opposite: `/usr/bin/python -> python3`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html?highlight=shebang#miscellaneous), using `#!/usr/bin/env python3` is still the recommended way -- but they admit that it does not always work:

> 2.4. Miscellaneous
>
> To easily use Python scripts on Unix, you need to make them executable, e.g. with
>
> chmod +x script
>
> and put an appropriate Shebang line at the top of the script. A good choice is usually
>
> #!/usr/bin/env python3
> which searches for the Python interpreter in the whole PATH. **However, some Unices may not have the env command, so you may need to hardcode /usr/bin/python3 as the interpreter path.**

The alternative is then to hardocode the python binary, i.e. `/usr/bin/python3` (or `python` in your case).